# Why my evaluate() always return 1 or 0, failed to evaluate the input prefix expression

Tags: c++, tree, expression, prefix, evaluate

I came across a problem with my evaluate() in my ExprTree() class. This function always only return two result, that is 1 or 0. I do not know why it always did like this. It is supposed to calculate the result of the input prefix expression, but it is not. I have spent the whole after to figure out this problem, but no result. Can someone help me to figure out this problem. Very appreciate!

Attached is the evaluate() with the evaluate() helper function.

```
/*
 //Data Members  
class ExprTreeNode   // inner node class
{
  public:
    /*---   Constructor   ---*/
    ExprTreeNode(char elem, ExprTreeNode *leftPtr, ExprTreeNode *rightPtr);

    /*---   Data Members   ---*/
    char dataItem;          // Expression tree data item
    ExprTreeNode* left;     // Pointer to the left child
    ExprTreeNode* right;    // Pointer to the right child
};
*/

/*Evaluates the value of the corresponding arithmetic expression.
*/
template <typename DataType>
DataType ExprTree<DataType>::evaluate() const throw(logic_error)
{
    //Throws logic error when the expression tree is empty.
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        throw logic_error("The expression tree is empty");
    }
    return evaluateHelper(root);
}

/*Helper function for the evaluate() function. Returns the vlaue od subtree pointed to by node
*/
template <typename DataType>
DataType ExprTree<DataType>::evaluateHelper(ExprTreeNode *node) const
{
    DataType l, r, result;
    if (isdigit(node->dataItem))
        //converts char to number
        result = node->dataItem - '0';
    else
    {
        //evaluates left subtree
        l = evaluateHelper(node->left);
        //evaluates right subtree
        r = evaluateHelper(node->right);
        //sum the left and right
        switch (node->dataItem)
        {
        case '+': result = l + r; break;
        case '-': result = l - r; break;
        case '*': result = l * r; break;
        case '/': result = l / r;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


//This is my main,please only read the test 1. When I use the input 4, the result is 1; when the input is the prefix expression +34, the result is 1 as well.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// 
//
//  Test program for the operations in the Expression Tree ADT
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

#include "ExprTree.cpp"
//#include "ExpressionTree.cpp"
#include "config.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Function prototype

template <typename DataType>
void dummy(ExprTree<DataType> copyTree);   // copyTree is passed by value

                                           //--------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
#if !LAB8_TEST1 || LAB8_TEST2 || LAB8_TEST3
    // Don't do this if testing boolean tree, unless also testing programming 
    // exercises 2 or 3 (for which this section is mostly needed).
    // The tricky part occurs if testing exercise 1 and (2 or 3), or if
    // someone is trying to test the basic class and one of the other exercises
    // in parallel. Hence the #if expression above.
    cout << "Start of testing the basic expression tree" << endl;
    ExprTree<float> testExpression;  // Test expression

    cout << endl << "Enter an expression in prefix form : ";

    testExpression.build();
    testExpression.showStructure();
    testExpression.expression();
    cout << " = " << testExpression.evaluate() << endl;

    // Test the copy constructor.
    dummy(testExpression);
    cout << endl << "Original tree:" << endl;
    testExpression.showStructure();
#endif

#if LAB8_TEST1
    cout << "Start of testing the boolean expression tree" << endl;
    ExprTree<bool> boolTree;
    cout << endl << "Enter a boolean expression in prefix form : ";
    boolTree.build();
    boolTree.showStructure();
    boolTree.expression();
    cout << " = " << boolTree.evaluate() << endl;
    cout << "** End of testing the boolean expression tree" << endl;
#endif

#if LAB8_TEST2
    cout << "Start of testing commute()" << endl;
    testExpression.commute();
    cout << endl << "Fully commuted tree: " << endl;
    testExpression.showStructure();
    testExpression.expression();
    cout << " = " << testExpression.evaluate() << endl;
    cout << "End of testing commute()" << endl;
#endif

#if LAB8_TEST3
    cout << "Start of testing isEquivalent()" << endl;
    ExprTree<float> same = testExpression;
    cout << "same is equal (tests copy constructor) ?  ";
    cout << (same.isEquivalent(testExpression) ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;

    ExprTree<float> empty;
    cout << "empty is equal?  ";
    cout << (empty.isEquivalent(testExpression) ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;

    ExprTree<float> userExpression;
    cout << "Enter another expression in prefix form: ";
    userExpression.build();
    cout << "new expression is equal?  ";
    cout << (userExpression.isEquivalent(testExpression) ? "Yes" : "No") << endl;
    cout << "** End of testing isEquivalent()" << endl;
#endif

#if !LAB8_TEST1 && !LAB8_TEST2 && !LAB8_TEST3
    // Don't bother with this if testing any of the programming exercises
    cout << endl << "Clear the tree" << endl;
    testExpression.clear();
    testExpression.showStructure();
    cout << "** End of testing the basic expression tree" << endl;
#endif

    return 0;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename DataType>
void dummy(ExprTree<DataType> copyTree)

// Dummy routine that is passed an expression tree using call by
// value. Outputs copyTree and clears it.

{
    cout << endl << "Copy of tree:  " << endl;
    copyTree.showStructure();
    copyTree.clear();
    cout << "Copy cleared:   " << endl;
    copyTree.showStructure();
}
```

Comment: *Attached is the evaluate() with the evaluate() helper function.* -- Where is the `main` program (part of the [mcve]) with the data that duplicates the issue?  Second, have you used your debugger to step through your program to discover where it goes wrong?

Comment: we need to see your input data. You could be a victim of integer division for instance...

Comment: In test 1 (`LAB8_TEST1`), `DataType` is `bool`, so `evaluateHelper()` can only return 1 (`true`) or 0 (`false`). For `bool` variables, any non-zero integer value assigned to it becomes the same `true` value.